# On delete child user, delete parent user and account associated with parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have relationship between User and account

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :account, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :child_users, :class_name => "User",:foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_one :filter, :dependent => :destroy

end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I delete user it deletes associated account and all its child user. How I can achieve on delete child user to remove parent and account related to its parent.

Same thing with Filter. On deleting parent user it should delete associated filter and also all filters who are associated with child(whose parent is deleted)

Thanks

Comment: Should it delete also all sibling users?

Comment: yes, on deleting parent it should delete siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something along the lines of

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :child_users, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_one :parent_user, :class_name => "User"

  after_destroy :destroy_parent

  def destroy_parent
    parent_user.destroy
  end
end
```

You'll probably have to make some adjustments in order to get it to actually work but hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.